# Angular controller not found or defined while doing lazy loading

Tags: angularjs

Hi  iam using Angular with Require. 
Require is managing my dependency sequence. Using lazy loading for loading controller and i was able to load my first home controller but when i wanted to navigate to dashboard controller then iam getting error dashboard controller is not found. hereis code

> main.html

```
<body ng-app >
    <div id="ViewPort"  ng-view>  </div>
 </body>
```

> shell.js

```
define(['mngRoute', 'mngSanitize'], function (ngRoute, ngSantize) {

var CMSapp = angular.module('CMS', ['ngRoute', 'ngSanitize']);

CMSapp.config(function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
    console.log($httpProvider);
    $routeProvider

       // route for the home page

        .when('/', { templateUrl: 'App/Partials/home.html', resolve: loader(['Home']) })

        .when('/Dashboard', { templateUrl: 'App/Partials/Dashboard.html', resolve: loader(['Dashboard']) })

});
CMSapp.run(function () {
    console.log('shell loaded');
    console.log(CMSapp);
});


return CMSapp;
```

> Home Controller.js

```
define(function () {

angular.module('CMS').controller('HomeController', ["$scope", "$http", 'MainService', function ($scope, $http, mainService) {
    $scope.message = 'Homess';

    $scope.InitializeController = function ()
    {
        console.log(mainService);
        mainService.initializeApplication($scope.initializeApplicationComplete, $scope.initializeApplicationError);
    }
    $scope.initializeApplicationComplete = function (response) {
        console.log('in default initializeApplicationComplete');

    }
    $scope.initializeApplicationError = function (response) {
        console.log('in default intialize error');
    }

}]);
```

});

> Home.html

```
 <div data-ng-controller="HomeController" ng-init="InitializeController()">
<span>{{message}}</span>
```

> Dashboardcontroller and dashboard.html are same only difference is the name

```
 define(function () {

angular.module('CMS').controller('DashboardController', ["$scope", "$http", 'MainService', function ($scope, $http, mainService) {
    $scope.message = 'Dashboard';

    $scope.InitializeController = function ()
    {
        console.log(mainService);

    }
}]);
```

});

> Dasboard html

```
 <div data-ng-controller="DashboardController" ng-init="InitializeController()">
<span>{{message}}</span>
```

> i was able to load home and able to bind with model, but this not in dashboard when i entered localhost:8999/Main.html#/Dashboard in url it gives error.

See the chrome console [Full console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnZxd.png)

> Angular, Route, Dasboardcontroller.js homecontroller.js shell.js are loaded successfuly no error in console only error is Dasboard controller is not a function, got defined

Comment: It should be `ng-app="CMS"` to initialize angular on page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `ng-app`, Angular will search for a module called `app`. If you want to specify a custom module, you need to tell it: `ng-app="CMS"`

I hope this works! :)

Comment: My angular app is bootstrapped and  i can see the home page, which is default according to routing defined.

Comment: So, when you go to the `#/Dashboard` route, it doesn't work?

Comment: @Rakesh, what that essentially means is that it's unable to find a controller named `DashboardController`. The define statements you're using isn't really recommended. Let me cook up a quick sample for you.

Comment: Thanks for the effort,  i was wondering if dashboardcontroller got itself registered (shown in image already attached) then why its saying not found.

Comment: Instead of logging the service, do something like: `console.log( "Dashboard controller registered" );`

Comment: Ya i think i already did that as in screenshot (Full Console2) dashboard line 3 is showing the angular App loaded with 2 controllers, so its loaded and registered. or did i miss something from your comment.

Comment: What's the order of loading these files? It matters.

Comment: jquery, angular, angular-route, shell, sanitize, animate, mainservice, homecontroller, dashboard html, dashboardcontroller, i think then controller should load first than html

Comment: jQ, Angular, Angular Route, < --- DEPS --- >, controllers, shell

Answer (score 2):

```
<body ng-app >
```

should be

```
<body ng-app="CMS">
```

because in your code you declare your module as so.

```
angular.module('CMS'
```

Answer (score 0):

Chrome console image [console2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrW7u.png) 
You can see my app is loaded bootstrapped and controllers are registered as well

Comment: Add this information as an edit, lest you should get a downvote.

Comment: thanks for the advice i did it you can check full console view.